# Update model from database does not add new table without pk (EF6)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I'm using ASP.NET MVC in VS2017 with SQL Server, when I add new table without pk from server explorer then I try to update model by this option (Update model from database) but new tables not added to edmx file

Comment: Any table ought to have a PK - if it doesn't have a PK, it's not even a real table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity framework requires a primary key in the table to be able to update records.